# Problems with the sending of emails via Swiftmailer after migrating to a new server using Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a technical question about **symfony 1.4**, I´m going to explain you the behaviour of an issue.

Recently, we´ve migrated our servers from **php 5.2** to **php 5.6**, before that all was right, but later of the migration we had a big issue with the sending of mails of the function **SwiftMailer**, in our database the number of restaurants(the table of the DB) in the big cities of my country were we have more than a hundred of restaurants in the platform DB have an issue for sending the email for all that amount of restaurants(usually more than 100 mails) that we have in the DB.

Can it be a question of the updating of the **php version** or the **Swiftmailer** function? Can I do a dose for the sending of emails(i.e sending 50 mails every 5 minutes) for fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Sending 100 e-mails is nothing. Check your logs to see what might be going on. Other than that, there are really no pointers in this question that can help us figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: For sure the version of SwiftMailer your are using is not compatible with PHP 5.6. As @Oldskool said, check your logs.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Sorry, if I don´t put the code, I have a foreach that check the restaurants in that city like this for send every mail:

foreach($restaurantes as $restaurante)
{
/*the doctrine query with the function $this->getMailer()->send($message);*/
}

Inside the foreach is sendig the emails, when are more than 100 usually have the issues.